# Formula for Natural logarithm of $\pi$

Tags: pi

Does any formula or expansion exist that gives $\ln \pi$ ?

The expansion should not just be any formula of $\pi$ with a $\ln$ before it. For example $\ln \pi$ = k + $\sum f(x)$ or something of this type.

Comment: take the logarithm of the Wallis product formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: Thanks ,that would work. But are there formulas that are specific with $\ln \pi $

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Ought to make that one an answer :-)

Comment: $\log \log \left((-1)^{-i}\right)=\log \pi $

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2082045/8530

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One could use [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310697/how-can-we-show-that-sum-n-1-infty-leftx-over-n-lnnx-over-n-right/2310703#2310703) to get

$$\ln(\pi)=\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[2\ln(n)-2\ln(n-0.5)-\frac1n\right]$$

Using the [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) of the Riemann zeta function,

$$2\ln(\pi)=\ln(6)-\sum_{p\in\mathbb P}\ln(1-p^{-2})$$

where $p$ is prime.

[Another interesting series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330515/prove-the-limit-exists):

$$\ln(\pi)=\ln(2)+2\lim_{x\to-1^+}\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^n\ln(n)$$

Comment: I'm looking for expressions like the one on top,but without other constants, but this was helpful though.

Comment: @Nimish Without other constants?  $2$ and $6$ and $\gamma$ and $0.5$ are too much?  I mean, its not like I'm using $\pi$ in the series expansions.  (Okay, maybe the $\gamma$ is a bit stretchy, since its a special constant :P)

Comment: I meant constants like $\gamma$,ideally the expansion should have only functions of natural numbers

Comment: @Nimish How about the third series I just edited in?

Comment: It was quite useful,appreciate it. If you are to stumble upon more let me know,would really appreciate it,thx :)

Answer (score 3):

Let the matrix $A$ be the lower triangular matrix defined as:
$$A=\text{If } n \bmod k=0 \text{ then } \frac{1}{n^c} \text{ else } 0$$
and let the matrix $B$ be the upper triangular matrix defined as:
$$B=\text{If } k \bmod n=0 \text{ then } \frac{n \cdot \mu (n)}{k^s} \text{ else } 0$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function.

Then the matrix product of the matrices $A$ and $B$ is the symmetric matrix $T$ starting:

$$T=A.B = \left(   \begin{array}{ccccccc}   +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&\cdots \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&-2&+1&+1&-2&+1 \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&-4&+1&+1 \\ +1&-1&-2&-1&+1&+2&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&-6 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{array}   \right)$$

which by analytic continuation has the Dirichlet generating function:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T(n,k)}{n^c \cdot k^s} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow s} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(z-1)}}}{n^c} = \frac{\zeta(s) \cdot \zeta(c)}{\zeta(c + s - 1)}$$

Then take the limit:

$$\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\zeta (c)-\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}\right)$$

which is equivalent to subtracting the first column in the matrix $T$.

Evaluate at $s=0$
$$\frac{\zeta '(0)}{\zeta (0)}=\log(2\pi)$$

subtract with $\log(2)$

$$\frac{\zeta '(0)}{\zeta (0)}-\log(2) = \log(\pi)$$

So by analytic continuation:

$$\log(\pi)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T_1(n,k)}{n^1 \cdot k^0}-\log(2)$$

where

$$T_1 = \left(   \begin{array}{ccccccc}   +0&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&\cdots \\ +0&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +0&+1&-2&+1&+1&-2&+1 \\ +0&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +0&+1&+1&+1&-4&+1&+1 \\ +0&-1&-2&-1&+1&+2&+1 \\ +0&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&-6 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{array}   \right)$$

$\log(2)$ can be subtracted from the matrix as a sum from the second column:

So again by analytic continuation (not numerically directly):

$$\log(\pi)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T_2(n,k)}{n^1 \cdot k^0}$$

where

$$T_2 = \left(   \begin{array}{ccccccc}   +0&+0&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&\cdots \\ +0&-0&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +0&+0&-2&+1&+1&-2&+1 \\ +0&-0&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +0&+0&+1&+1&-4&+1&+1 \\ +0&-0&-2&-1&+1&+2&+1 \\ +0&+0&+1&+1&+1&+1&-6 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{array}   \right)$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The $ \sin $ function has the beautiful representation as a product
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1- \frac{x^{2}}{n^2 \pi^2 }\right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $x= \frac{\pi}{2}$ and we have the Wallis product formulae for $\frac{\pi}{2}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\pi}{2} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n}{2n-1} \frac{2n}{2n+1} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Taking logarithms of this will give
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln \pi = \ln(2)+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2\ln(2n) -\ln(2n-1) -\ln(2n+1) \right) .
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

One has $\zeta'(0)=\log{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, and there are plenty of different ways of expressing this: for example,
$$ \lim_{s \downarrow 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}\log{n} = \log{\sqrt{2/\pi}}. $$

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\log{n} $ does not converge by itself, but can be regularised in various ways: for example, if $S_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (-1)^n\log{n}$ we have
$$ S_{2m}+S_{2m+1} = 2\sum_{n=1}^{2m} (-1)^n\log{n}-\log{(2m+1)}, $$
which can be written in closed form as
$$ \log{(\pi/2)} + \log{\frac{m!}{\Gamma(m+3/2)\Gamma(m+1/2)}} $$
Stirling's formula implies that the second term converges to $0$, so
$$ \log{\pi} = \log{2} + \lim_{m \to \infty} 2\sum_{n=1}^{2m} (-1)^n\log{n}-\log{(2m+1)}. $$

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1131002), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2n)-1}{n+1}=\frac32-\log(\pi)
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can also derive that 
$$1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\ln(1-\frac{1}{4n^2})+4n coth^{-1}(2n)-2\right)=ln(\pi)$$
If we use $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ln(sin(x)) dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}ln(2)$ and replace $sin(x)$ by it's Euler product, we get
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ln(x \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2})) dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}ln(2)$$
We can replace the product by a summation to arrive at
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ln(x) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty ln(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}) dx$$
Which equals
$$\left| xln(x)-x \right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ln(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}) dx$$
We see 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} xln(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x}} \stackrel{\frac{-\infty}{\infty}}{=} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}} =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -x = 0$$
For the integral we see
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ln(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}) dx =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ln(1-\frac{x}{n\pi}) + \ln(1+\frac{x}{n\pi}) dx\\
 = \left|(x-\pi n)(ln(1-\frac{x}{\pi n})-1)+(x+\pi n)(ln(1+\frac{x}{\pi n})-1)\right|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
=(\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n)ln(1-\frac{1}{2n})+\pi n -\frac{\pi}{2}+(\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n)ln(1+\frac{1}{2n})-\pi n -\frac{\pi}{2}\\
=\frac{\pi}{2}ln(1-\frac{1}{4n^2})+\pi n(ln(1+\frac{1}{2n})-ln(1-\frac{1}{2n}))-\pi\\
=\frac{\pi}{2}(ln(1-\frac{1}{4n^2})+4n\coth^{-1}(2n)-2)$$
So we see
$$-\frac{\pi}{2}ln(2)=\frac{\pi}{2}ln(\frac{\pi}{2})-\frac{\pi}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{\pi}{2}(ln(1-\frac{1}{4n^2})+4n\coth^{-1}(2n)-2))$$
Dividing by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and swapping some terms yields
$$ln(\pi)=ln(2)+ln(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\ln(1-\frac{1}{4n^2})+4n coth^{-1}(2n)-2\right)$$